# Как сделать видимыми приложения из глобальной области в вновь создаваемых виртуальных средах

Tags: python, виртуальная-машина

Существует ли инструмент, позволяющий организовать доступ к библиотекам установленным глобально из локальных виртуальных сред?
Пример:
То есть глобально установить какую-нибудь библиотеку (flake8, например) и чтобы в каждой новой виртуальной среде flake8 был доступен.

Comment: Сделать скрипт который будет все это сразу устанавливать в новую среду... Виртуальная среда создается для того чтобы разделить пакеты в глобальном и виртуальном окружении, а Вы пытаетесь их объединить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать используя [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) с плагином [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Когда создаете новый virtualenv с помощью `pyenv` (в терминологии pyenv это называется версия), то при этом вы указываете, какую существующую версию использовать. Системный питон (а так же и любой другой установленный с помощью `pyenv`) может быть использован в качестве такой базовой версии. И значит, что все пакеты установленные туда, будут доступны в новом виртуальном окружении.